# Formalism in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

How inner product of two vectors (generalizing the dot product   in three dimensions)give a complex number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors in introductory linear algebra are often assumed to consist of real numbers. However, other varieties of vectors are available !

The elements of the vectors used in the matrix formulation of quantum mechanics are complex numbers. In other words, they form a complex vector space. The inner product of two vectors in a complex vector space can be a complex number.

In a complex vector space the geometric interpretation of the inner product $\vec a.\vec b = |a||b|\cos \theta$ does not really apply.